# python for loop with "reducing" list

Tags: python, list

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
for loop in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[loop]%2==0:
        a.remove(a[loop])
        loop = loop - 1
```

I want to reduce the list by filtering numbers which can be divided by 2. There are two questions here:

- I know this is a stupid method, is there a better (or a more pythonic) way?
- If I really want to use the for-loop to tackle this task, as the actual filtering rule for the list is more complicated than 'dividable by two', I found that the 'iterative variable' `loop` is not reduced by one as expected in `R`, how can I make it working?

#### update 01

Thanks for the prompt reply, first part of the question is solved, but what about the second part? What if I want to use for-loop to deal with it and make the `loop` to be reduced by ` if the condition of 'dividable by two' is fulfilled?

Comment: I would try adding every item for which the predicate does not hold to a new list

Comment: so if it is divisible by two you want to reduce it by 1 is that right?

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар yes, the loop should be reduced by 1 as a becomes `[1,3,4]` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all the elements from the list, if it is not divisible by 2, then the best way is to create a new list without the numbers not divisible by 2, like this

```
[item for item in a if item % 2 != 0]
```

You can also use the `filter` function, like this

```
filter(lambda item: item % 2 != 0, a)
```

If you are using Python 3.x, then you need to generate the list of items from the `filter` object using `list` function, like this

```
list(filter(lambda item: item % 2 != 0, a))
```

Apart from these methods, if you want to do in-place replacement, then you might want to do it in reverse, like this

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
for loop in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
    if a[loop] % 2 == 0:
        a.remove(a[loop])
```

**Note:** Whenever possible, prefer list comprehension method.

Comment: He wants to keep only odd numbers so you should change your lambda function in filter to: lambda x: x%2

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski Just realized it and changed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension can do the trick:

```
# Define data in variable a
a = [1,2,3,4]
# Apply the list comprehension to filter list a
a = [i for i in a if i%2==0]
```